# [Better Solution?]Category based form

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, dynamic

I am busy making a multi-shop shopping site like amazon.com, ebay, carousell.com etc...

Now when users create a listing I made a custom fields system that get the custom fields from a mysql table then outputs them into the form.

The Code:

Okay so first this is the `listings` table:

| ID | list_title | list_brand | seller_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two sticks | Mr Sticks | 1012 |

Then we have `listings_meta` which is where I store the custom fields like for a pillow it would be `type of filling` or for a stick it would be `color of stick`:

| ID | listing_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | stick_color | brown |

Now the meta key comes from a database table called `[form_fields]` which is linked the the categories like this

`[form_fields]`:

| ID | meta_key | type | meta_link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | stick_color | select | 0 |
| 2 | stick_length | input | 0 |
| 3 | rock_weight | input | 0 |
| 4 | brown | option | 1 |
| 5 | blue | option | 1 |

And the category table`[cats]`:

| ID | category |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Sticks |
| 5 | Stones |

Link custom fields and categories`[cat_meta]`:

| ID | meta_id | cat_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 |

So now that you know how the items link with each other lets dive into the PHP code:

Now fist when a user clicks create product that will be given a popup asking which category they want to list the product thats done with a simple select query then they will be redirected to a new page called `new_product.php?cat=[id of category from database ID]`

`new_product.php?cat=4`
Now some of the fields are the same for all products they are the ones in listings table
But for custom fields its a bit more complex
:

```
<input type="text" name="list_title " placeholder="Title">
</br>
<input type="text" name="list_brand " placeholder="Brand">
</br>

<?php //get custom fields from custom_inputs table 
        
        //query the database for fields id and
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `meta_id ` FROM `cat_meta` WHERE `cat_id` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['cat']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt_results = $stmt->get_result(); // get result
        while($row_get = $stmt_results->fetch_assoc()){
            $field_id[] = $row_get['meta_id ']; //store all id's in array
        }
        if(empty($field_id)){ //no custom field found in database
            return 0;
        }else{
            foreach($field_id as $field_id){ //loop ID's to get multiple
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `meta_key `, `type ` FROM `form_fields` WHERE `ID` = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $field_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt_results = $stmt->get_result(); // get result
                while($row = $stmt_results->fetch_assoc()){
                    $field_name[] = $row['meta_key']; //get key aka title
                    $field_type[] = $row['type']; //get the type of input
                }
            }
        }

foreach ($field_name as $index => $field) { //combine the type and meta key
    $type = $field_type[$index];

    if($type === "select"){ //field type is a select 
        echo '</br><select name="body['.$field.']">';
        echo '<option selected Disabled value="">Select Option</option>'; 

        //get options from `form_fields` linked to this meta_id
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `meta_key` FROM `form_fields` WHERE `meta_linked` = ? AND `field_type` = 'option'");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $field);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt_results = $stmt->get_result(); // get result
        while($row = $stmt_results->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value='.$row['meta_key '].'>'.$row['meta_key'].'</option>'; 
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }


    if($type === "input"){  //field type is a user input
        echo "<input name='body[$field]' placeholder='$field'>";
    }
}
?>
```

Yes I know the code is very messy but I will clean it up before it is pushed but my issue is I feel like this seems over-complex/not efficient, Can anyone recommend a better way to build custom fields based on the category that was selected.

Also i do not include a lot of html and other php processing code as i dont think it needs to be included but if you need more info i will give it :)

Comment: Your code is one long string of statements. You don't use functions, or, may I say, classes. It would be nice to have a function/method that would return a list of all properties from the database, and another with all the possible values of a property. Talking about that, you need to work a bit on how you name things. A table name like `form_fields` is not what I would use in a database, I would use something like `product_properties`. It goes on. You, understandably, use the term `users`. Are you talking about buyers or sellers? It appears you mean sellers, but why not call them that?

Comment: Oh, I had no room for this anymore in my first comment, but your database design looks good to me, apart from the names.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for all the info This code is actually in a few functions but i moved it for this purpose as i found it might be a bit long to write in the Q also i dont use classes as this is not OOP PHP this is procedural php but i want to switch to oop as its much cleaner and to work in groups of devs and for my naming yes i need to work on it lol i will try and change the names. generally do you think i could optimize anything else?

Comment: It is not a good idea to give us just a summary of your code, without the functions you use. We only review working code, that is actually used, and complete. We're not afraid of a bit of code. This is not Stack Overflow. It is useless to suggest optimization only to hear: "Yes, I already did that, but didn't include this in the question.".

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i fully understand thanks for telling me I will update the post and make sure to include my code as is without changing it :D ~ Have a great day and i really appreciate your words. You have helped me learn more today!

Comment: @KIKOSoftware also i call them `users` as `sellers` can also be `buyers` its a two way system so find it might work better to just call them `users`

Comment: Sorry, you missed the point. I said it was understandable you called them `users`, exactly for the reason you mention. I was simply referring to the use of accurate terminology, including in your question. It was just something that confused me, when I read your question. It might just have been me, because if I read your question back, I think there's no reason for that confusion. In similar vain: You know what "cats" are, right? Meow! What stops you from calling them "categories"? I found, after decades of programming, that naming things accurately safes a lot of time. For everyone involved.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware lmao "Meow" you make a good point yes i need to work on my naming sorry. I honestly want to thank you :D I will implement all of your points before I push the code to github